# Empty outputInfoList for second graphic card

Tags: c++, directx-11, dxut

I have two discrete video adapters on my PC: GTX 1060 and RTX 2080 ti.
I would like to use second one for my DXUT app. I found command line argument **-adapter#** to specify it, however, my program crashed when I run with **-adapter1**  (1 is adapter ordinal for RTX2080) option.
I started debugging and figured out the following issue: *EnumOutputs* returns only *DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND*.

For GTX1060 first *EnumOutputs* call returns correct output.

Code section:

```
HRESULT CD3D11Enumeration::EnumerateOutputs( _In_ CD3D11EnumAdapterInfo* pAdapterInfo )
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IDXGIOutput* pOutput;

    for( int iOutput = 0; ; ++iOutput )
    {
        pOutput = nullptr;
        //next line returns at once DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND for RTX2080
        hr = pAdapterInfo->m_pAdapter->EnumOutputs( iOutput, &pOutput ); 
        if( DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND == hr )
        {
            return S_OK;
        }
        ...
}
```

```
        hr = EnumerateOutputs( pAdapterInfo );
        if( FAILED( hr ) || pAdapterInfo->outputInfoList.empty() ) //failed here cause second condition is true
        {
            delete pAdapterInfo;
            continue;
        }
```

Who know how to fix this problem?

All drivers are up to date.

P.S. I [also tried](https://www.itechtics.com/use-specific-gpu/) to specify graphic card via Windows and GeForce software, but It seems appropriate only for laptop case with both integrate/discrete cards.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my God..
The problem is only GTX1060 connected to my monitor.

My tutor explained me that it's impossible to render frame buffer in this case.

Comment: In order to use two GPUs at the same time for *rendering* then you need a solution like NVidia SLI or AMD CrossFire, but these require you have *matching* GPUs. With a mix of both NVIDIA and AMD in the same machine, you can only do "heterogenous compute" with one of them and rendering the other.

Comment: PS: Make sure you are using the [latest DXUT for DirectX 11](https://github.com/microsoft/DXUT/).